# Change Activities overview backdrop (Ubuntu 19.10)

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, activities-overview, 19.10

GNOME 3.34 automatically applies a dark filter to the background in the application overview page for "readability".

Background image with darkening:
[image: BG image with darkening]

Background image without darkening:
[image: BG image without darkening]

Is there a way to disable or customise the amount of darkening here?

Answer (score 2):

There are GNOME Shell extensions that can do what you want, but first you need some preparation.

To install any GNOME Shell extension, you need to have `chrome-gnome-shell` installed:

```
sudo apt install chrome-gnome-shell
```

You also need the *GNOME Shell integration* browser extension installed. You can install the extension in Firefox by visiting [this page](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gnome-shell-integration/) and clicking the *Add to Firefox* button or in Chrome, by visiting [this page](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gnome-shell-integration/gphhapmejobijbbhgpjhcjognlahblep?hl=en) and clicking the *Add to Chrome* button.

You may also install Tweaks to access the extensions' options (and a bunch of other useful GNOME settings):

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

Now, you can install either the [No Dark Overview](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1352/no-dark-overview/) or the [Darker Overview](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1177/darker-overview/) GNOME Shell extension, by visiting the respective extension's website, toggling the switch on the right-hand side of the extension to *ON* and clicking *Install* on the pop-up. You may need to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, input `r` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to restart GNOME Shell to make the extension take effect.

To disable an extension, go to *Tweaks* → *Extensions* and toggle the extension you wish to disable to *OFF*. To uninstall an extension, visit its website and click the "X" button on the right-side.

---

A couple of things about these extensions:

- [No Dark Overview](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1352/no-dark-overview/) completely removes the Overview background and that's all the extension does.
- [Darker Overview](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1177/darker-overview/), on the other hand, provides you with two settings, shown in the screenshot below:

  [image: Darker Overview settings]

  *Overview darkness* changes the darkness of the Overview background (*0=normal, 11=black*, as shown in the description of the option), while *Show vignette* toggles the vignette effect of the Overview *ON* or *OFF*.

---

**Note:** Both extensions haven't been updated for quite a while and show that they support GNOME versions up to 3.26. In fact, the [No Dark Overview GitHub repository](https://github.com/freeroot/no-dark-overview) doesn't seem to exist anymore and [Darker Overview GitHub repository](https://github.com/mkoura/gnome-shell-darker-overview) shows that the extension's latest update was on February 2018. For the latter, however, there is a comment stating that it works in GNOME 3.34 too.

I have Ubuntu 18.04 and I can confirm that both extensions work fine in this version, but you have to try them yourself to see if they actually work on Ubuntu 19.10.